# FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Tags: php, runtime-error

I have a function I built that will grab a .csv file and upload information stated then, creating an account for each user in the .csv file.

My issue is I need to be able to do this with thousands of entries in a .csv file but my problem is I get this time out error and not to sure why, as follows:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
c:\php-fastcgi\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity 
                             timeout
Detailed Error Information

Module -
FastCgiModule

Notification - 
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler - 
PHP_via_FastCGI

Error Code -
0x80070102
```

Here is my CSV function:

http://jsfiddle.net/fS4t4/ - this is in PHP and I just throw it into the javascript section.

How to fix this?

UPDATE: My provider is Winhost

Comment: Which version of IIS are Winhost using? I'm guessing IIS 7.0 since that and 8 were listed on the site.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.ini` and locate the ActivityTimeout parameter; copy it into the [php] section. Change the parameter to whatever value you would like, and also make sure that it is not commented out. Restart IIS and you should be good.

`activityTimeout` can be also set (IIS7 and above) from the IIS Manager under the server/IIS/FastCGI Settings/Edit.

Comment: Where would I get this becuase I am using winhost as my provider>

Comment: I have never used winhost, but if you do not have access to Windows Explorer on the server, you may be out of luck. I would recommend contacting their support and asking how to edit your `fcgiext.ini` in order to get an answer specific to winhost

Comment: Any idea of how to actually fix processess that really shouldn't take forever but are break FastCGI due to running too long?

Comment: I couldn't find this file on IIS 7.5 / Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Would anything "bad" happen if I set the number to 10000 seconds?

Answer (score 55):

`activityTimeout` can be also set (IIS7 and above) from the IIS Manager under the server/IIS/FastCGI Settings/Edit.

Comment: Oh dear, now this looks like I'm trolling for people's edits to get rejected. I'm not very sure what qualifies as an edit or as a comment, but do consider commenting first :)

Comment: haha why? I think I probably should have put my answer as a comment of yours since it was your answer the one who put me in the right track. I just feel it easier to do it through the GUI than editing the XML file ;-)

Comment: Upvotes to all! Although this definitely should have been a comment on @icedwater's answer, or an edit to the answer directly. Edits are encouraged in the community because they keep answers up to date while maintaining the concise nature that is StackOverflow. Here's a link giving a bit more info on when an edit is relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Answer (score 49):

For **IIS 7.5** you can change the setting of file in

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config**

and find the line below and change as per your requirement

```
<fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" idleTimeout="900" activityTimeout="180" requestTimeout="10000" instanceMaxRequests="10000" />
</fastCgi>
```

DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART SERVER

**OR**
This can be done from UI too:

Open InetMgr (window+R type Inetmgr and hit enter)
[image: open inet manager from run command]

[image: Filter Fast CGI in inet manager]

[image: double click or click edit fastcgi]

[image: modify fastcgi setting]

[image]

Comment: Thank-you for the screenshots! Was an immense help in finding where to change this setting.

Answer (score 30):

For Windows Server 2008 R2, the default version of IIS that is supplied is IIS 7.5. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902642/1091386) Dave suggested will not work because that file isn't there.

Instead, try `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` to set up the options for the entire server. Look at the `<fastCgi>` block:

```
<fastCgi>
    <application fullPath = "C:\php\php-cgi.exe" arguments = "" 
        monitorChangesTo = "" stderrMode = "ReturnStdErrIn500" maxInstances = "4"
        idleTimeout = "300" activityTimeout = "30" requestTimeout = "90" 
        instanceMaxRequests = "5000" protocol = "NamedPipe" queueLength = "1000" 
        flushNamedPipe = "false" rapidFailsPerMinute = "10">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PHP_MAX_REQUESTS" value="5000" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </application>
</fastCgi>
```

Remember to restart your webserver.

I set the `activityTimeout` to 90 and `requestTimeout` to 270 to give processes more time to finish their work. This wasn't enough for my problem, but it should at least allow people to find the relevant bits on IIS 7.5.

Comment: I did so on IIS 7.5. now I got ***ERR_CONNECTION_RESET***

Comment: Via the IIS Manager this is in the Connections > [Server] > FastCGI > click on the php-cgi.exe > click Edit