# The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout even after setting activityTimeout

Tags: php, iis, timeout, fastcgi

The following is my code in php:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$sql="select * from Words where `Ph`=\"to be added\"";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $url = 'http://somewebsite.com?word='.$row["Word"];
    if (!$str = file_get_contents($url)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "<font color='red'>FORGET ".$row['Word']."</font><br>";
}
else{
    preg_match_all("/<div>\/(.+?)\/(,<img  url=.*>)<\/div>/s", $str, $matches);
    $sqlupdate="UPDATE Words SET `Ph`=\"".$matches[1][0]."\" WHERE `Word`="."\"".$row["Word"]."\";";
    echo $sqlupdate."<br>";
   }
}
```

This deals with 2679 records. I have been running this from my localhost and the database is in a remote server. I have changed the timeout of CGI to 01:15:00, Application timeout of FastCGI Application to 1200, Instance MaxRequests to 10000, Request Timeout to 1200, and yet I keep getting the error. I can only prevent the error if I narrow down the number of records to be updated by specifying a range in the query. I have been doing this for a while now, but I was wondering if there is a solution to this problem since that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried this ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); //2 min

Comment: Does this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14902642/1003917

Comment: Edited every time related parameter I came across. Nothing seems to work. Now I am manually entering values for ranges to process no more than 500 records at one go